# Inserting values in to oracle table using jsp

Tags: java, sql

I am using the following code to insert values in to a table.

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO APPLICATION VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,TO_DATE(?,'DD/MMYYYY'),?,TO_DATE(?,'DD/MM/YYYY'),?,?,?,?,?,SYSDATE,'X',?)";
PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
pstmt.setInt(1,Integer.parseInt(sr));
pstmt.setString(2,nm);
pstmt.setString(3,(String)session.getValue("ITSGTYP"));
pstmt.setString(4,pst);
pstmt.setString(5,dox);
pstmt.setString(6,zo);
pstmt.setString(7,dob);
pstmt.setString(8,cdr);
pstmt.setString(9,cdrdt);
pstmt.setString(10,qual);
pstmt.setString(11,mail);
pstmt.setString(12,bond);
pstmt.setInt(13,Integer.parseInt((String)session.getValue("USER")));
pstmt.setString(14,request.getRemoteAddr());
pstmt.setString(17,place);
```

The description of the table into which the values are inserted is as follows

```
EMP_ID                    NOT NULL NUMBER(6)
NAME                      VARCHAR2(25)
APPLN_TYP                 VARCHAR2(10)
POST                      VARCHAR2(100)
DIV                       VARCHAR2(25)
ZONE                      VARCHAR2(5)
DOB                       DATE
CADRE                     VARCHAR2(5)
CADRE_DATE                DATE
QUALIFICATION             VARCHAR2(100)
EMAIL_ID                  VARCHAR2(70)
BOND                      VARCHAR2(3)
SUBMITTED_BY              NUMBER(6)
SUBMIT_IP                 VARCHAR2(30)
SUBMIT_DATE               DATE
FLAG                      VARCHAR2(1)
PLACE                     VARCHAR2(20)
```

While executing the above code I am getting the following error

```
 Error: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index
```

This query was working fine before.

My previous table didn't have the `PLACE` column. I had to insert it at a later point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace  `pstmt.setString(17,place);`

with

`pstmt.setString(15,place);`

The reason for error you get is :

You don't have 17 `?` symbols in your query for prepared statement, you only have 15 `?` symbols that means you can only set 15 values (for 15 columns) for that prepared statement.

Now what you were doing is you were setting a parameter at 17 th index and you don't have any column specified at index 17 in your query,   you only have 15 columns and 15 `?` symbols for the values to be inserted at respective 15 columns.

So replace it with what I mentioned above and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

It's safer to include the columns names you want to insert into the SQL statement like:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO APPLICATION VALUES (EMP_ID,NAME, ....)   // etc   
(?,?,?,?,?,?,TO_DATE(?,'DD/MMYYYY'),?,TO_DATE(?,'DD/MM/YYYY'),?,?,?,?,?,SYSDATE,'X',?)";
```

In this way, you have more control of the indexes and the columns you are using in your statement.

Answer (score 0):

In your query u have 15 parameters to set. And you are trying to give value of 17th index. You should change it to 15 instead of 17.

i.e

pstmt.setString(15,place);